# Built-in Fonts in Windows, Mac, ChromeOS, and Linux

Tags: css, fonts, google-fonts

What are the built-in fonts in the computer (Windows, Mac, ChromeOS, Linux) that is supported by the CSS font-family property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the default fonts (called web-safe fonts)
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp